# How to identfy pattern with arbitrary content python and remove it

Tags: python, string

how can I identify a certain pattern of a string in python to remove it? What I want to do clean my string at every occurence of `{$arbitrary}`

```
my_string = "hello. This is my example of {$test} {$foo} {$string} my string"
my_string = my_string.replace("{$arbitrary}", "")
```

```
Output I want:
hello. This is my example of    my string
```

Comment: what's not working in your current code?

Comment: I dont want to replace exactly arbitrary. That is more like a placeholder. I dont know how many of these are in there and what the exact content is. I only know the pattern {$...} and I have no idea how to identify them all

Comment: so, you're asking how to create a string that looks like `${foo}` if `arbitrary = "foo"`?

Comment: My string looks like `s = "my name is {$A} and {$B} {$C} and i like {$D}"` And i want to remove all 4 of them, but I dont know whether they are called A B C D or anything else about it or the string.

Comment: Seems like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: How would that look like @JohnColeman? I tried so much and I doesn't work: `x = re.findall(r"\b(\{\$})$\}", txt)` should look for any word that begins with "{$" and ends with "}" but it just doesn't return any result